# exporting metadata from gps camera to spreadsheet

Tags: gps, metadata, digital-image-processing

I have a question involving exporting metadata from a GPS camera to an application such as a spreadsheet.

In essence, I'm working with a significant number of images taken with a GPS digital camera. The GPS coordinates are embedded in the metadata that is accessed when you open the “properties” tab on the jpg file.

Is there a computer program or tool available that can extract that metadata automatically and put it into a file that can be manipulated (e.g., put the GPS coordinates in a spreadsheet)?

Comment: EXIFextractor http://www.br-software.com/extracter.html

Answer (score 2):

And a free option is [BR's EXIF extractor](http://www.br-software.com/extracter.html). Lovely little program that does the job well. It's been saying that it is in beta for a few years now. I've never had any issues with it.

[edited to add link - Luke,thanks for the heads up]

Answer (score 1):

On the ArcGIS stack, there is the [Geotagged Photos to Points tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000165000000).

Reading the EXIF GPS fix is a fairly easy thing to do, it should be possible in Python using something like using [`PIL` (sample)](https://gist.github.com/erans/983821) and [`xlwt` (sample)](https://github.com/python-excel/xlwt/blob/master/xlwt/examples/simple.py).

Answer (score 1):

Spatialite-gui has a tool "Import EXIF photos" for that. The current Spatialite version is 4.2 but this old document is still valid https://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-2.3.1/spatialite-exif-2.3.1.html. You can also easily export the data from Spatialite into other formats like txt/csv or dbf with another tool in Spatialite-gui.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use ESRI's solution ArcGIS to export GPS camera trails to a spreadsheet, please see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6WdhQWmkJio

Comment: Welcome to the site Maksim.  Please consider making this a stand-alone answer (i.e. one that does not rely on the existence of a link).  Otherwise, the answer becomes defunct if the website does.  Alternatively, you could convert this answer to a comment.  Please see the related help center article: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.